How to Share Links to AWS Resources?
I am trying to keep note of certain Step Function executions by copying their URL but when I log out and log back in, the URL stops working and I get the error:
This session is invalid or has expired. To continue, try clearing your browser cookies and refreshing the page or sign in again.

How can I share/save links to specific Step Function executions (and other AWS resources in general) without the URL breaking after the session ends? It seems my credentials are encoded in the URL and I am not sure how to prevent that.
For example, one of the executions I am interested in: arn:aws:states:us-east-1:<account_number>:mapRun:CacheLoader/DistributedCacheLoad:
Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

I found the solution. URL I copied looked like:
https://<account_number>-stz5h3sj.us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/map-runs/details/arn...
Removing the part before us-east-1 resolved the issue.
New URL that works looks like:
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/map-runs/details/arn...

AWS provides “console links” that are static and session-independent. These links look like this:
https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/states/home?region=us-east-1#/...

So i think the account_id part should be removed.
